# Simplest and most efficient way to turn raw bytes in an unsigned int to a string

Tags: c++, string, data-manipulation

In C++ what is the simplest and most efficient way to turn the raw bytes in an unsigned int to a string (to read for example by ASCII codification)?

An uint64_t contains 8 bytes, I would like to interpret these bytes as (char*), append the termination flag ('\0'), and convert to string. This way I can store the "raw" data in the shortest possible string.

For example, suppose we have the uint16_t containing the bits 0100 0001 0100 0001 (I believe here each 8 bit sequence is 'A'). I would like to have these in a string str such that (str == "AA") is true.

What I mean to ask is how can I store some data such as int in the most space-efficient way inside a string without compression.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the purpose of the null terminator if valid strings can contain null characters?

Comment: You need to provide some relevant examples of your exact input and output.  Bear in mind that endianness could be a factor here, and as already mentioned the input bytes may also contain zeros.

Comment: You mean like [std::tostring](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) or something else? Can you give an example?

Comment: You could use `std::ostringstream` to convert to a textual representation.

Comment: Added example @paddy

Comment: Your example is unclear.  You just said "contains" and do not specify what to do with nulls.  You must also define "efficient".  Are you trying to save storage, or instruction cycles?  Choose one.  If it's storage, then why convert to string at all?  A pointer alone will require as many bits as your data (assuming 64-bit OS), then you probably have memory management overhead and the string itself which (if it's a standard null-terminated string) will be _at least_ 9 additional bytes, so that potentially uses even more space because of padding too.

Comment: Using whole bytes isn't possible because of the null problem that @orlp mentions.  Base64 would be more efficient than the usual base 10, and keep everything in ASCII.

Comment: @paddy addressed

Comment: Why a `string` and not a `string_view`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll leave my original answer down below, but the most efficient solution appears to be also the simplest (proposed by @Remy Lebeau down below):

```
std::string string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&value), sizeof(value));
```

If you're using C++17, you can also use std::string_view and avoid a copy and heap allocation altogether:

```
std::string_view string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&value), sizeof(value));
```

Of course, all of this dances around the very simple nature of C string representation. All we're doing here is telling the language to interpret the address of the integer as a C string. If you really care about space and execution efficiency and can't use C++17 then perhaps just use C strings.

**Original solution:**

This solution still suffers from the endianness consideration, but given that all major architectures are little endian, that should only be a consideration in a network context. std::string can accept an iterator over bytes. It automatically adds the null terminator.

```
uint64_t value = 100;
const uint8_t *const bytes = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(&value);
std::string string(bytes, bytes + sizeof(uint64_t));
```

Comment: But it doesn't guard against getting a null byte in the middle of the string.  Yes the `string` object will be complete, but too many functions that take strings will truncate something with an embedded zero byte.

Comment: @MarkRansom The iterator will be copied from beginning to end, even if there are null bytes. This is useful for packing/unpacking binary data in a std::string. I don't see how that applies given the nature of the question.

Comment: Yes, I admitted the `string` object will probably hold the null bytes correctly.  But you will almost certainly call a function with that string that will truncate it, leading to a hard to track down bug.

Comment: @beta No need to use iterators when you know how many bytes to copy. `std::string` has a constructor that accepts that size, eg: `std::string string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(value));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nice, even better from a heap allocation perspective.

Comment: Isn't `string_view` C++17 feature?

Comment: Indeed. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of 'fastest' it depends on your architecture, e.g for Intel it would probably be something along these lines:  https://godbolt.org/z/9n6cz6Wss

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void u64_to_str(uint64_t n, char str[17]) {
  // a few constants
  const __m128i _9 = _mm_set1_epi8(9);
  const __m128i ascii0 = _mm_set1_epi8('0');
  const __m128i asciiA = _mm_set1_epi8('A' - 10);
  const __m128i x0F0F = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0F0F);
  const __m128i swizzle_mask = _mm_set_epi8(
      8, 0, 9, 1, 10, 2, 11, 3, 12, 4, 13, 5, 14, 6, 15, 7);

  // split each byte into a nibble (wrong byte ordering here)
  __m128i b = _mm_and_si128(x0F0F, _mm_set_epi64x(n, n >> 4));

  // are we greater than 9?
  __m128i cmp = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(b, _9);

  // select correct ascii value to add! 
  __m128i acsii_offset = _mm_blendv_epi8(ascii0, asciiA, cmp);

  // convert nibbles to ascii values to 0 -> 'F'
  b = _mm_add_epi8(b, acsii_offset);

  // shuffle to correct ordering
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)str, _mm_shuffle_epi8(b, swizzle_mask));

  // terminate string
  str[16] = 0;
}
```

if you simply want a way to convert bytes to strings quickly whilst sticking to standard C/C++ (without the expense of allocating the contents of a std::string), then just do:

```cpp
void u8_to_string(uint8_t a, char str[2]) {
  char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  str[0] = hex[a >> 4];
  str[1] = hex[a & 0xF];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to interpret the 8 binary bytes as a string, you can do:

```
uint64_t val = 0xAAAAAAAA;  // or whatever
char buf[sizeof(val)+1];
memcpy(buf, &val, sizeof(buf));
buf[sizeof(val)] = '\0';  // apply NUL terminator
const std::string s(buf);
```

Note that if any of the bytes in `val` are 0, then your string will be terminated at that byte, due to the NUL-terminating semantics of C-strings.

Note that `sizeof(string)` is 24 on my system (MacOS/X); on other platforms it might be 16, but it will probably never be 8 or less, which means that you won't be saving memory by storing `uint64`'s as `std::string` in any case.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking, thank you. Even though I did not consider initially that the string would be terminated at any 0.

Comment: I'll wait a bit to see if someone addresses the 0 termination, otherwise I'll give you the accepted answer.

Comment: One more note:  The order in which the bytes appear in `buf` will be different depending on whether your CPU is big-endian or little-endian.  (i.e. on a little-endian CPU, the least-significant byte will be `buf[0]`, while on a big-endian CPU, the most-significant byte will be `buf[0]`)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Though BSD, and more recently, glibc on Linux, supports [`htobe64`/`htole64` and `be64toh`/`le64toh` functions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htobe64) that will let you normalize the byte order portably for any given host (when the byte order is already as expected for that host, the functions are no-ops).

Comment: @ShadowRanger there are also `htonl` and `ntohl` which are older and more universal I think.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The downside being that they work on `long`, which might not be a 64 bit quantity (and isn't on most 32 bit machines and any version of Windows; of course, on Windows, you have to use [other APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-htonll) because of course you do).

Comment: "*if any of the bytes in `val` are 0, then your string will be terminated at that byte*" - only because you are treating it that way. If you use the `string` constructor that takes a 2nd parameter for the character count, the string won't be truncated. And, you won't have to null-terminate the input buffer, either. `const std::string s(buf, sizeof(val));`